# Django admin returning whole object not just the FK field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have searched and found a  few answers however all the questions relate to the use of **str** etc...

Im using the django admin module as it is interesting to play with and saves times, im having slight issues with my foreign keys in the sense they are returning all the field values not just the foreign key value.

relevant models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    Order_ID =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Dept_ID =models.ForeignKey(Department)
    Status =models.ForeignKey(Order_Statu)
    Order_Total =models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)

    def __str__(self):
           return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.Order_ID, self.Dept_ID, self.Status, self.Order_Total)


class Order_Item(models.Model):
    Order_ID =models.ForeignKey(Order)
    Itm_Name =models.ForeignKey(Item)
    Quantity =models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
           return '%s %s %s' % (self.Order_ID, self.Itm_Name, self.Quantity)
```

and an example of what i mean:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4repM.png)

im willing to admit that it is probably something i have overlooked in the documentation or it is something simple and obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the line that is the reason you are getting it like that

```
def __str__(self):
           return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.Order_ID, self.Dept_ID, self.Status, self.Order_Total)
```

if you want only id then you need

```
def __str__(self):
           return self.Order_ID
```

the thing you declare in the model str function is the thing you get everywhere,

Comment: Thank you! i knew it was going to be something stupid